# How could I go about removing duplicate data obtained from an API?

Tags: json, swift, api

I have a list of venues from my API that is in JSON format, however multiple duplicates come up. I.e. certain events would be at a venue, such as mary poppins, some others would be at one venue. Therefore multiple duplicates of that venue comes up. Like mary poppins, rihanna, beyonce at the o2 arena. From the api it would display 3 of the same venues.

How would I go about removing the duplicate data?

Comment: Do you have access to the API code, you better select distinct results from the API.

Comment: do they all have unique identifiers?

Comment: @wain i don't think so

Comment: so ow do you define them as duplicates?

Comment: @wain i don't think i have defined them as duplicates, I'm not really sure what to do :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These things are duplicates because they have the same name? or address? or some other unique identifier.

When you process your JSON data you need to look at the database you already have and run a quick search to see if you already have a thing with that same unique identifier.

If you don't, create a new one. If you do, link to the existing one.